# Find all the faces between a source and a target faces

Tags: cgal

I've used the `CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path` before to find the exact shortest path in a topological manner. But now I want something simpler that seem to be missing from the library that is finding the **logical** path from one face to another, returning a list of the faces in between.

Is there any way to do it without having to implement a tree search from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGAL offers a class `Dual` as a wrapper around a mesh. As the name suggests you obtain a [dual graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph).  If your mesh has boundaries you have to filter them out with a `boost::filtered_graph`. Now you can run [`boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html). Now for any vertex the predecessor map will lead you to the source vertex.

You can find a self contained example [here](https://gist.github.com/afabri/1990e06e64b4c2f06568b56ae0399a87).

You probably can add a visitor so that you stops by throwing an exception as soon the shortest path algorithm reaches your target vertex.